# all empty Immutable.Lists are identical

Tags: immutable.js

Feature or bug: All empty Immutable.Lists test as identical.

For example:

```
var xxx = new Immutable.List();
var yyy = new Immutable.List();
xxx === yyy;   // true

var zzz = yyy.push(1).pop();
zzz === yyy;    // true

zzz = Immutable.fromJS([]);
xxx === zzz;    // true
```

I can see why you might want to consider all empty lists as identical, but I also have use cases where just because 2 lists are empty doesn't imply that they are the same.  As a counter-example, if I create two Immutable.Lists with the same contents, they do not test as identical.

Is there a way to tell 2 empty Lists apart?

Do you think this is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in Immutable.js nor a contributor, but I will try to write down some thoughts in immutable data structures.

Immutable.js is optimized for performance. Especially for performing equality checks. The idea behind immutable is, that if we have immutable data structures, we can determine if a structure changed simply by comparing the references. The first thing the implemention of `Immutable.is` does is checking if the references are equal:

```
export function is(valueA, valueB) {
  if (valueA === valueB || (valueA !== valueA && valueB !== valueB)) {
    return true;
  }
  // ...
}
```

If they are the same, we can always assume that the structure is still the same, since it is immutable. Making all empty lists equal increases performance here.

What we also need to understand is, that immutable data structures are widely used in functional programming languages ([Immutable.js is actually inspired by Scala and Closure](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js#immutable-collections-for-javascript)). Functional programming languages are much closer to mathematics than other languages. Mathematics is value based, this means in mathematics there are no instances. We would assume that a set containing the elements 1, 2 and 3 is equal a set of 1, 2 and 3. The empty set is always equal the empty set. The empty list equals the empty list.

Some interesting results from the Scala REPL:

```
scala> List(1, 2, 3) == List(1, 2, 3)
res0: Boolean = true

scala> Nil == Nil
res1: Boolean = true

scala> 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil == List(1, 2, 3)
res2: Boolean = true
```

Comment: which is why I'm inclined to think it's not a bug. However,
`new Immutable.List([1,2,3]) === new Immutable.List([1,2,3])`
does not evaluate as true, so there is a bit of inconsistency here.  While evaluating empty structures as equal is cheap, I assume we'd want to avoid the deep compare at all costs.  I'd been working under the assumption that different instances were in fact different, regardless of their content. Hence my question.